# Why are there American-style vehicles in "Mad Max: Fury Road"?

Tags: mad-max-fury-road, worldbuilding

In "Mad Max: Fury Road," Nux's car has the steering wheel on the right, as you'd expect in an Australian car. Likewise, the car Max is driving in the cold open has its steering wheel on the right. On the other hand, Immortan Joe's car and Furiosa's rig both have their steering wheels on the *left*, like American cars. What gives?

Comment: Is it actually *set* in Australia, like the older films were? (it wasn't *filmed* here, though it was originally planned to be).

Comment: I don't think it's ever specifically stated, but the accents and geography check out. See my answer for details.

Comment: @Adeptus: If it's not set in Australia then the question still stands, though it would be the opposite: why the right-hand-drive cars?

Comment: @slebetman If it's set somewhere else, it could be possible to drive from a left-hand-drive country to a right-hand-drive country (eg, UK to Europe)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Lots of US muscle cars are being brought over to Australia currently, as the law now states that if they are older than 30 years, they are able to be registered as a classic and don't need to be converted over to right-hand drive. Also, lots of drag racer companies prefer to use left-hand drive in top-end full-body cars (as opposed to fibro-body or rail cars) due to the weight of the driver being on the left assisting with balance. Torque from the engine tries to twist the car up and to the right and extra weight in the left can offset this.

The relevant legislation for registering vehicles in the state of Victoria can be found [here](https://www.vicroads.vic.gov.au/~/media/files/documents/safety-and-road-rules/vsi18_web.pdf?la=en).

Also, there's no real indication that the film is *actually* set in Australia like the previous ones, but it can be safe to assume through the accents and geography that it is. The location of the Citadel could be in the Blue Mountains, and Bullet Farm and Gas Town could have been built around the [Lithgow Small Arms Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithgow_Small_Arms_Factory) and the [Clyde Refinery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clyde_Refinery) respectively. Coming down out of the Blue Mountains brings you to a heavily vegetated area that might have been the Green Place that Furiosa was trying to flee to, and heading east over the salt wastes could have been the Tasman Sea into the Pacific Ocean.

Comment: And Holdens wouldn't hold up in the apocalyptic future. As Midnight Oil sang: _Holden wrecks and boiling diesels steam in 45 degrees_ ;-)

Comment: "Lots of US muscle cars are being brought over to Australia currently" - this is true, around my area in Victoria there are lots of car meets quite regularly. It's not uncommon to see old American cars out for a drive.